# Footer is centered and I need it left

Tags: html, css

I have a class assignment and on all the other web pages the footer is on the left but on one page its near the center.  I've spent a long time trying to figure it out to no avail and its frustrating!!  I can include whatever info someone needs to help me.  Thank you.

## footer {

```
clear: both;
margin-left: 190px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #666666;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 75%;
font-style: italic;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
float: none;
```

Comment: Start by posting your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Is it a public facing page? If so include a link to the broken page and a working page.

Comment: Can you post some HTML and CSS.  Without there isn't anyway to troubleshoot it.  Also add any code that you have already tried.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8iJIwJ4NcnKUFg3Um1fZDlWRmM/view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8iJIwJ4NcnKUUFlNl9GZ05uWHM/view

Comment: No you need to add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 190px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    float: none;
```

Comment: I have it as an id selector and the footer is correct on the other pages but I must have something floating that's interfering with the footer being where it needs to be.

Answer (score -1):

It's entirely possible that you have a piece of content in an element above your footer that's causing this issue. If you have a piece of content above which is floated, and a footer which is not (or vice versa), the layout of one affects the other.

It would be best if you could post your code, or a link, so that we could take a look.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: How so? I advised that another element may be affecting the flow? Is that not an answer?

Comment: #footer {

    clear: both;
    margin-left: 190px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    float: none;

Comment: Answers don't usually contain questions like "It would be best if you could post your code, or a link, so that we could take a look."

Comment: Footer tag was in the wrong place, I needed to move it down outside  the one div tag</div>
    <div>
        <footer id="footer">
            Copyright &copy; 2014 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
            <a href="mailto:darren@rector.com">darren@rector.com</a>

        </footer>
    </div>